# Problem in inserting row to custom database table

Tags: wpdb

I have a custom table in database named `wp_tasks` which has 5 fields.

But I am unable to insert the current time to `assign_date` field.

**wp_tasks table**

```
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
worker_id INT(6) ,
project_id INT(6),
work_id INT(6),
assign_date DATETIME
```

**Inserting records**

```
function insert_record_to_db( $worker_id, $work_id, $project_id ){
    global $wpdb;
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'tasks';
    $data = array(
        'id' => "",
        'worker_id' => $worker_id,
        'project_id' => $project_id, 
        'work_id' => $work_id,
        'assign_date' => date( "Y-m-d H:i:s" )
    );
    $format= array( '%d', '%d', '%d','%s');
    $wpdb->insert( $tablename, $data, $format );
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You've just forgot a value in the $format array. There are 4 values but in the $data array you have 5. It's to be equal.

Comment: or just remove 'id' => "",

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. This should be work for you

```
function insert_record_to_db( $worker_id, $work_id, $project_id ){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert(
        $wpdb->prefix . 'tasks',
        array(
            'worker_id' => $worker_id,
            'work_id' => $work_id,
            'project_id' => $project_id,
            'assign_date' => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time('timestamp') )
        ) 
    );
    // $wpdb->insert_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do here is remove the:

```
'id' => "",
```

from the data array.

Also, to simplify your database creation, you don't need to do your get_var(), you can just change your SQL command to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name
```

This way you let the db handle creation of the table without the need of an extra SQL statement before hand.